# Redirecting From Android Application To Wordpress

Tags: android, wordpress

I have `Wordpress` Website and I am building an android application for that.
For one case I want to redirect to my wordpress web site from android application. How can I handle cookies and sessions?
I have same database for wordpress and Android application.
I am able to do login from android and now I want to redirect same user to my wordpress web site.

Please help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is little bit confusing, if you just want to launch your website from APK then follow this link whcih allow you to generate APK easily,

[Android Bookmark Creator](http://makeapk.com/index.php?r=site/makeapk)

But if you want to make customized APP, then You can either make your own RESTFUL API or use wordpress XML-RPC.

[XML-RPC Tutorial Wordpress](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/xml-rpc-in-wordpress--wp-25467)

[XML-RPC for android Open Source Project](https://code.google.com/p/android-xmlrpc/)

But for this, you need to have good knowledge in android

Comment: Thanks for reply Sir, I have created customized android app. but for e-commerce i want to redirect user to my web site how can i do that..?